# Widgets are not displaying in the admin panel

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, widgets

I am using WordPress, I have an issue with the widget. I am not getting the widget in the WordPress admin panel.

I am getting the error in the console

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: null has no properties
> /wp-includes/js/dist/edit-widgets.min.js?ver=7ac5bb27bb662c888b918bc66c0a0a65:2

Any idea how to solve this?

I have disabled my all the plugins but still getting the error in the console.

[image]

Comment: I would report this to WP via Trac as it looks like a bug in WordPress core. Try using the gutenberg plugin as it may have newer versions of that file, otherwise you may need to change theme and disable all plugins, then flush out any inactive widgets to try and get a clean slate again. Definitely report this though as if you do not it may not get fixed

Comment: @TomJNowell, I have deactivated all my plugins but still the same issue. Changed the custom theme from twenty-one but still the same issue..

Comment: @TomJNowell, I can see the search, Recent Posts, Recent Comments, Archives, and Categories on the page but not in the admin panel

Comment: @TomJNowell, I used the Classic Widgets plugin and I got all the widgets. https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-widgets/ . What do you think? Where is the issue?

Comment: I don't know, there's not enough information to pin down the problem

Comment: @TomJNowell, Ok. Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: I have never encountered this issue on any site on any version of WP

Comment: @TomJNowell, Ok.